# Is it possible to say "Did you catch the meaning?"

Tags: phrase-choice, colloquial-language

Is it possible to say

> 1. Did you catch the meaning?
> 2. Did you catch what I'm trying to say?

In order to express/ask if somebody understand something.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's used as *did you **get** the meaning?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is Yes: In this usage, "catch" is synonymous with "comprehend."

However, in everyday speech, a native speaker would be more likely to phrase it as:

> Did you catch **my** meaning?

Comment: True, although I might use _"Did you catch **the** meaning?"_ in the case where we both had just listened to the same speech, joke, remark, or monolog (or maybe, _"Did you catch **her** meaning?"_).

Comment: @J.R. I was less than clear. I meant that the specific thought "Did you catch what i'm trying to say?" would be phrased with "my meaning." I ought to edit it, I suppose...